# chrome extension to open link in new tab - no error, but does nothing on click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a really simple chrome extension to open a hard-coded link in a new tab when clicked, and I'm not having any luck.  After adding the extension the icon shows up, but nothing happens when I click on it.  Any suggestions?

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Drive Button",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Open Google Drive",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"background": "background.html",
"permissions": [
"tabs"
]
}
```

background.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://drive.google.com"});
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some problems in your script

- Manifest registration
- CSP

### Manifest registration

You should register background as

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

or

```
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
```

### CSP

If you are looking to have background as a `html` page eliminate `<script>` tag in html page to adhere [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

After Eliminating these problems i got your script running.

### Working Version

**manifest.json**

Registered background page to manifest file.

```
{
    "name": "Drive Button",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Open Google Drive",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

Used your code without any modifications.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "http://drive.google.com"
    });
});
```

I was able to create window as expected.

## References

- [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)
- [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)

Comment: +1 for structured and clear answer. Need to start doing the references thing, good for new devs.

Comment: answer appears very simple, but if you observe closely there are lots of place where your code can go wrong ... @Sudarshan ... can u suggest some debugging techniques too .. i am a noob to chrome's platform